# What IPC is used between an application and a library in Linux?

Tags: linux, libraries, shared-library, ipc

When you have a Linux application that depends on a library (dynamically-linked), how does the application communicate with the library? What [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) method is used?

Comment: If the library is not creating its own process (and most don't), then Marcus' answer is correct. In the rare circumstances where the library actually spawns a new process, the IPC mechanism can be anything, but is usually shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. Because a dynamically linked library lives in the same process' memory space - and thus, no second process exists with which you need to do IPC.